# objective c Black screen between Splash Screen and First Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

When i click on app icon i will see Black screen(it will appear for 1 second) between Splash Screen and First Screen, if i remove splash screen i will see black screen(it will appear for 1 second) and than my main controller load. How i can change color that black screen, maybe some global settings.

My general settings

[image]

and info.plist

[image]